# Disappeared characters in String But Accessed with index

Tags: c++, string

In the following program,

```
int main()
{
  int i;
  string a;//unallocated string;

  for( i=0;i<26;i++)
  {
     a[i]=i+97;// trying to write a char at index i of a
  }
  cout<<" a[i] : ";

  for(i=0;i<26;i++)
  {
     cout<<a[i];// printing the characters 
  }

  cout<<"\n a as string : "<<a; // the string disappeared
}
```

> Output :
>
> a[i] : abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
>
> a as string :

My questions are

- Where are the characters stored at the indices of string a reside ?
- Why there is no error when I try to write in an unallocated string ?
- Can someone explain what is happening  ?
- I'm using gcc with c++11

Comment: You are writing aggressively in unallocated memory, that's what going on. Where are they stored? Somewhere undefined. Why no error? Because C and C++ doesn't check for bad programming.

Comment: Undefined behavior.

Comment: Try `a.at(i) = i + 97;` instead of `a[i] = i+97;`.  Watch what happens.  Your "error checker" is the `at()` call.

Comment: [See this using your code](http://ideone.com/DDkHqd).  Now look at [this example](http://ideone.com/amx5Py) using `at()`.  The former is undefined behavior, the latter will not let you get away with an out-of-bounds access without throwing an exception.  So it's not as if you have to cross your fingers and hope you didn't make a mistake with indexing.  You have `at()` for those instances where you want bounds checking and you want to address a possible indexing bug.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thank you. I understood my mistake. But I'm curious to know where those characters will be in the memory in case of undefined behaviour ?

Comment: @SelvaJove Probably if short string optimization was done, those characters may have wound up in the internal char array that's used.  That is just a theory, and you shouldn't rely on this to be the case in all circumstances.  You could have easily crashed the program -- try stuffing 1,000 characters into the string instead of 26.

Comment: @GuillaumeF. Though you're right at compile time, Visual Studio will error on this toy example when run in Debug.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you do `a[i]` you are using [`string::operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at) which explicitly says:

> Returns a reference to the character at specified location pos. No bounds checking is performed

`a` is default constructed so it will have a size of 0. You are trying to index outside those bounds, so anything you read or write there is undefined.

It looks like you're using 26 as a magic number for the upper bound for your loops. Instead use `size(a)` (or before C++17 use `a.size()`). Then if you wanted to execute your loops 26 times, just initialize `a` like this: `string a(26, '\0')`

[<kbd>Live (Slightly Improved) Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/fgbYy9)

**EDIT:**

As [pointed out by AndyG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38109352/disappeared-characters-in-string-but-accessed-with-index/38109471?noredirect=1#comment63652958_38109471) C++ does provide us with better ways of initializing our `string`s in this case [`iota`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) is an excellent choice. Instead of your initialization for loop you could use:

```
iota(begin(a), end(a), 'a')
```

I've updated the example to include this.

Comment: Or better yet, OP shouldn't write a loop at all. Use something from `<algorithm>` like `std::transform`

Comment: Do you have any clue where they will be in the memory ? I'm curious to know that @Jonathan Mee

Comment: @AndyG I believe [`iota`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) would be preferable to `transform` in this case. I've updated my answer cause I agree that's helpful information.

Comment: @SelvaJove Sure, they're written to that index of memory, without checking bounds. before your initialization loop, `data(a)` contained: '\0' after your initialization loop the address of `data(a)` and the next 26 bytes of memory had been stomped by the alphabet. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yeah that's a good idea. Perhaps use a range-based for loop for printing, or alternatively an `ostream_iterator`

Comment: @AndyG I mean I thought about doing an `ostream_iterator` for the output loop but honestly I see little point in optimizing that, when we can just do: `cout << a` and ditch the loop all together.

Comment: That's fair. Probably what OP wanted, but didn't know that `<<` was defined for `std::string`

Comment: @AndyG The insertion operator being defined for `string` is nice, but if you're coming from [tag:C] the extraction operator being defined for `string` is gold.